# How to make this stencil invisible and disabled but all another features keep enabled(rotate, flip...) in react-advanced-cropper

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image-cropper

The problem is that i want to make this stencil and overlay invisible and disabled but all another features keep enabled(rotate, flip...) in react-advanced-cropper
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhjxq.jpg)

Is there any props in this library to keep stencil and overlay disabled? I was trying to write some css code and to add overlay above cropper but it is not that result i would like to achieve. I would appreciate if someone help me with this

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add some minimal code example to your question, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the stencil 'invisible' and maximize it to fit the whole image using the default position. If you rotate the image probably you'll have to maximize again using onChange event.

```
                <Cropper
                    ref={cropperRef}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    src={src}
                    className={cn('default-cropper__cropper')}
                    stencilProps={{
                        handlers: false,
                        lines: false,
                        movable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                    }}
                    defaultPosition={defaultVisibleArea}
                    
                />
```